# Apache-POI / XSSF - Read big file (5 MB)

Tags: excel, apache-poi, readfile, xssf

I've a big file with 10000 rows... Opening it, lasts an eternity... After 10mins I stopped the programm...

```
OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(item.getFilePath());
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
sheet = workbook.getSheet(item.sheet);
evaluator = new XSSFFormulaEvaluator(workbook);
itRows = sheet.rowIterator();
```

the `itRows = sheet.rowIterator(); newer finishes...`it needs so much time...

How can I read such a big file?

Comment: 10,000 rows isn't that many, and requesting a sheet iterator should be really quick. Are you sure that it isn't hanging somewhere else?

Comment: this time, I had another problem as well... but though, loading the file needs much time... and if the file gets bigger, heap space error occurs as well... so I'm now using a SAXParser in combination with the XSSF Lib to iterate over the data without loading it beforehand...